# Why Spring RowMapper return the last record only from the result set?

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, ojdbc

i am trying to retrive ( users that have provider) from 2 database tables(ADMIN_USER and PROVIDERS) using sql query statement

`"Select ADMIN_USER.ID UserID, ADMIN_USER.USER_NAME Name, ADMIN_USER.PASSWORD Password, ADMIN_USER.FULL_NAME fullName , ADMIN_USER.PRIVILEGE, ADMIN_USER.PROVIDER_ID ,PROVIDERS.ID providerID,PROVIDERS.USER_NAME provider  from ADMIN_USER,PROVIDERS  where ADMIN_USER.PROVIDER_ID=PROVIDERS.ID",`

and this is my method
 `public List getUsers() {

```
    return DS.query(sqlQuery,new RowMapper<User>() {

                        public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                                throws SQLException {

                            User user = new User();
                            user.setId(rs.getInt("UserID"));
                            user.setUserName(rs.getString("Name"));
                            user.setPassword(rs.getString("Password"));
                            user.setFullName(rs.getString("fullName"));
                            user.setPrivilage(rs.getString("PRIVILEGE"));

                            Provider provider=new Provider();
                            provider.setId(rs.getInt("providerID"));
                             provider.setName(rs.getString("provider"));
                             user.setProvider(provider);

                            return user;    }}); }`
```

but it returns the last record only from the Method (result-set) as the list.size() show the size=1  not 4 !

i think the join is true as the resulted record show correct join, but i think the problem in RowMapper ?

is there another way or method to retrive data from 2 joined tables using (spring, JDBC,NamedParameterJdbcTemplate) ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tested this query outside of java to see that it is returning the results you are expecting? Also, what is DS? I can show you an example using jdbcTemplate if you are using spring.

Comment: yes, i tested it and works well -- DS is NamedParameterJdbcTemplate object --- please if u have an example using more than one table give me it , and try to tell me the reason of this result  ?!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you are trying to accomplish using spring's NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

```
public class UserRepo {

    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private static final String sqlQuery = "Your query here";


    //Assuming you are using spring and have a datasource bean defined named datasource
    @Autowired
    public UserRepo(Datasource datasource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(datasource);
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
       List<User> results = jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, new UserMapper());
    }

    private static final class UserMapper implements
                RowMapper<User> { 

        mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        User user = new User();
        user.setId(rs.getInt("UserID"));
        user.setUserName(rs.getString("Name"));
        user.setPassword(rs.getString("Password"));
        user.setFullName(rs.getString("fullName"));
        user.setPrivilage(rs.getString("PRIVILEGE"));

        Provider provider=new Provider();
        provider.setId(rs.getInt("providerID"));
        provider.setName(rs.getString("provider"));
        user.setProvider(provider);

        return user;    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just make sure all your column name aliases in the sql statement match up with what you are trying to map them to in the rowMapper.

Comment: IT is the same result as it return the last record only and the size of the returned list is 1 not 4  @Ericf